# pip uninstall broken w/ --environment flag?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I can't seem to get pip to uninstall a package when using the environment flag.

I've created a virtual environment:

`virtualenv --no-site-packages /path/to/testenv`

While not in the virtual environment, I issue:

`pip install --environment /path/to/testenv django`

Django is downloaded and installed.

If I do the same command in reverse, it doesn't work:

`pip uninstall --environment /path/to/testenv django`

The uninstall command outputs:

> Uninstalling Django: Proceed (y/n)? y
>   Successfully uninstalled Django

But if I actually go in to the virtual environment:
`. /path/to/testenv/bin/activate`

and then run the uninstall command:
`pip uninstall django`

I get:

Uninstalling Django:

> /path/to/testenv/bin/django-admin.py
>   /path/to/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg-info
>   /path/to/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django
>   Proceed (y/n)?

I'm running pip 1.0

Am I missing something, or did I hit a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in pip 1.0.  Seems to work if I `pip install --upgrade pip` and then try it.